# Django query selecting values and objects

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with the queries when selecting values and objects. Here is a sample structure:

```
class Property(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=70,  blank=True, verbose_name="Property Name")
   type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Agreement(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="prop")
    renter = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Kiracı", related_name = "renter01")
```

**Here is the first filter.**

```
 qs1 = Agreement.objects.all()
```

This one returns property and renter as objects. So I can refer the object details such as

```
for q in qs:
   print(q.renter.firstname)
```

**Here is the second filter.**
When I need only some fields I use this filter:

```
qs2 = Agreement.objects.all().values('renter',...)
```

In that case the query returns the pk value of the renter user; and I cannot use it as object.

Is there a way that I can select certain columns and keep the objects in it as objects?

Answer (score 2):

If you want renters, you should query User, not Agreement.

```
renters = User.objects.exclude(renter01=None)
```

(Note, having `renter01` as the reverse relation makes no sense; unless you have a good reason, you should keep it as the default, which is `agreement_set`.)

Comment: This is just a simplified example. Assume that there are many foreignkeys. Assume that I have many fields in Agreements and will use them. The basic question is "how to select certain fields by keeping them as objects when they are objects."

Comment: Well firstly this is almost certainly an over-optimisation. But if you really want to do this, that is what the [`defer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#defer) and [`only`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#only) methods are for.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I checked defer and only in shell. I still get all fields and their values. When I checked the description I see that "Whenever you call only() it replaces the set of fields to load immediately." So defer and only are for immediate load but when you try to read the field that is in defer you can still get the value. What is more defer and only is not working for reverse relations. Am I right? Thanks again.